# After uninstalling iBooks, I can't sign in to iTunes any more

Tags: itunes, books

I am currently using El Capitan.

Every time I uninstalled iBooks so I could manage my books with iTunes, I found I simply couldn't sign in to iTunes any more. That means I click the 'sign in' button but no sign-in window pops up. I can't purchase or re-download any of my music or books.

And reinstalling iBooks fixes it all.

Is there a way I can manage my books with iTunes and can still sign into my account?

Answer (score -1):

- Uninstall iTunes 12.3.x
- then install iTunes 12.2.x.

Seems as if 12.3 must have iBooks not so with 12.2.2.